# Error cannot coerce class ‘"mads"’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, r-mice

Hello am trying to fit logistic model but am getting these error

```
fit.mis<-glm(Probation ~ Times_UP+Library+Activity,family=binomial,mar)

Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"mads"’ to a data.frame
```

am not very expert in r ..
does any body can help

Comment: Looks like mar is a class of mads, and is an output from *mice* package? *glm* requires input as dataframe, so it is failing to convert.

Comment: mar is an output of ampute() in mice package

Comment: i have try to convert

Comment: mar<- as.data.frame(mar) ...  but still i got the same error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the amputed data (result of `ampute`) to fit a model you can extract this with

```
mar$amp
```

in your example

```
fit.mis<-glm(Probation ~ Times_UP+Library+Activity,family=binomial,mar$amp)
```

more info can be found [here](https://www.gerkovink.com/Amputation_with_Ampute/Vignette/ampute.html)